# Producer-consumer queue in python

Tags: python, sockets, multiprocessing, queue, pyaudio

I'm using a producer consumer model in order to stream audio via sockets to PyAudio. I have one process receiving data from sockets, process, then putting it in a queue, while the other process gets data from the queue and writes it to the stream. While this is working, I am getting underflows + clipping during parts of the stream. My code is essentially as such

Process1

```
CHUNK = 1024
q = queue


data = s.recv(CHUNK)

#processes data

if q.qsize() < CHUNK * 2: #arbitrary value
    q.put(data)

while q.qsize() > CHUNK:
    time.sleep(5) 
#I use this to allow the queue to be emptied
#by the stream and manage my memory somewhat.
```

Process2

```
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16, channels=CHANNELS, rate=RATE, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK, output=True)

while True:
    if q.empty() is False:
        stream.write(q.get(), exception_on_underflow=True)
```

I did some logging to log data before and when an underflow exception is shown and what I get noticing was that underflow would only ever occur when q >= CHUNK (e.g. 1025,1026), or upon initial filling of the stream to 1024, and the stream.get_write_availble was always > 15000 out of a total 16384. I know the stream is being starved of data but I don't quite understand why and how this is possible when the queue is never empty (e.g. there is always data to be read into the stream). Any help is appreciated.